# How do you use css keyframes animations with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to make an object move with CSS keyframes by adding the animate property to a class. So that when you click on a certain button the class will be attached to the object, thus creating an animation? Here is the code for [it](http://jsbin.com/sexetozeqe/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
function start(){
  document.getElementById('up').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('red').className = "uppy";
  };

  document.getElementById('do').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('red').className = "downy";
  };
}

start();
```

```css
#area {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#red {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: red;
}
#btn-row { margin-top: 20px; }

div.downy {
  -moz-animation: down 1s;
  animation: down 1s;
}

div.uppy {
  -moz-animation: up 1s;
  animation: up 1s;
}

@keyframes down {
  from { top: 0; }
  to {top:5 0px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes down {
  from { top: 0; }
  to { top: 50px; }
}

@keyframes up {
  from { bottom: 0; }
  to { bottom: 50px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes up {
  from { bottom: 0; }
  to { bottom: 50px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="area">
  <div id="red"></div>
</div> 
<div id="btn-row">
  <button id="up">Up</button>
  <button id="do">Down</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work in JSBin, so I copied it over to jsfiddle. Once I added `position: absolute` to the `#red` element, it worked! (might need some tweaking, but that's up to you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `position` to `relative` at `#red` element, `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards` at `.downy`

```js
function start() {
  document.getElementById('up').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('red').className = "uppy";
  };

  document.getElementById('do').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('red').className = "downy";
  };
}

window.onload = start;
```

```css
#area {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#red {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: red;
  position:relative;
}
#btn-row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

div.downy {
  -moz-animation: down 1s;
  animation: down 1s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
div.uppy {
  -moz-animation: up 1s;
  animation: up 1s;
}
@keyframes down {
  from {
    top: 0px;
  }
  to {
    top: 50px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes down {
  from {
    top: 0px;
  }
  to {
    top: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes up {
  from {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 50px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes up {
  from {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="area">
  <div id="red"></div>

</div>
<div id="btn-row">
  <button id="up">Up</button>
  <button id="do">Down</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, is there a way to continue moving the object downward as I continue to click on the button. Or would I have to create something like that with javascript?

Comment: Should be possible, though beyond scope of actual Question _"Is there a way to make an object move with CSS keyframes by adding the animate property to a class."_ ? Would need to change `from {
    top: 0px;
  }` which begins `down` animation at `0px`

Answer (score 0):

change javascript to :

```
<script>
        function start() {
              document.getElementById('up').onclick = function(){
                 document.getElementById('red').className = "uppy";
              }

              document.getElementById('do').onclick = function(){
                document.getElementById('red').className = "downy";

            }
        }
        window.onload =start;

    </script>
```

insert  'position:relative;' to  #red in css to :

```
#red{ height:25px; width:25px; background:red; position:relative;}
```